# How to limit work linked to a build by branch specification

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I see this feature is available, but I can't seem to get it to work the way I expect it to. Am I misunderstanding the capabilities of this feature?

When creating a build pipeline there is an option (since 2017) to automatically link a build to work items. Under this option is an **Include** and **Exclude** list for branch specifications. The default is `Include *` which searches all branches for work to link since the last successful build.

[image]

I'm trying to implement a branch naming convention because we have many solutions in the same repository and don't want work items relating to system 1 to be linked to the build of system 2.

To do this I'm using an `Include sub2/*` branch spec, but the build doesn't seem to link correctly.

#### Custom Branch Spec

[image]

---

#### Change on Branch Outside Spec

[image]

#### No Other Commits Linked to the Work Item

[image]

#### The Work Item Still Shows on the Build

[image]

**BUT** the build doesn't create an `Integrated in Build` link on the work item.

### For changes made WITHIN the branch spec

The functionality of the build showing the work items in the progression *(seen above)* includes the work item as expected, but the `Integrated in Build` link is still not added to the work item.